# Angular 7 custom pipe not found

Tags: angular

I've searched for hours on stackoverflow, found answers that works for other but for the life of me, I can't get it to work.  I don't know what else to do, driving me crazy.

filter.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
 ........
}
```

shared-pipe.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FilterPipe } from './filter.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FilterPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    FilterPipe
  ]
})
export class SharedPipeModule { }
```

search-issue.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedPipeModule } from '../../../../pipes/shared-pipe.module';
import { SearchIssueComponent } from './search-issue.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedPipeModule,
    SearchIssueComponent
  ]
})
export class SearchIssueModule { }
```

search-issue.component.html

```
  <ul *ngFor="let ticket of tickets | filter: searchText">
                                      ^^^^^^^
```

filter pipe not found here.

I've tried anything and everything I can think of but nothing works.  All answers on stackoverflow the codes above should work, but it doesn't for me.

I've tried to import filter.pipe.ts directly into the search-issue.module.ts and app.module.ts, with same results.

Any thoughts?

Much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Could you post the complete message from Angular CLI build?

Comment: Btw, the SearchIssueComponent sholdn't be "imported". It should be "delcared"

Comment: Added the screenshot.  Do you mean declare sharedpipe on SearchIssueModule? I've tried that as well.  There are no error messages on the cli just on the html page itself.

Comment: In SearchIssueModule, move SearchIssueComponent inside the "declarations" array. Also, remove the space before "searchText"

Comment: NVM, that worked.  WTH, spent hours trying to figure this out.  Thank you so much, made my day.

Comment: Any idea why I get an error (the image above) and not in the CLI?  It's detected in Angular that it's a pipe but the browser, no.

Comment: Compile using --aot, and see what CLI has to say